# Combining 2 SQL Tables with same Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two sql views in sql-server-2008. Both have columns `ITEM_NO`, `QTY`, and `LOCATION`.

view_1:

```
-----------------------------------
|  ITEM_NO  |  QTY  |  LOCATION   | 
-----------------------------------
|  SN-15    |   0   |    SEA      |
-----------------------------------
|  XY-45    |   2   |    SFO      |
-----------------------------------
|  TY-14    |   1   |    SEA      |
-----------------------------------
```

view_2:

```
-----------------------------------
|  ITEM_NO  |  QTY  |  LOCATION   | 
-----------------------------------
|  HN-34    |   1   |    SEA      |
-----------------------------------
|  GJ-13    |   4   |    SFO      |
-----------------------------------
|  RB-02    |   7   |    SEA      |
-----------------------------------
|  AJ-13    |   9   |    LAX      |
-----------------------------------
```

I want to combine these into a single view, that would look like:

```
-----------------------------------
|  ITEM_NO  |  QTY  |  LOCATION   | 
-----------------------------------
|  SN-15    |   0   |    SEA      |
-----------------------------------
|  XY-45    |   2   |    SFO      |
-----------------------------------
|  TY-14    |   1   |    SEA      |
-----------------------------------
|  HN-34    |   1   |    SEA      |
-----------------------------------
|  GJ-13    |   4   |    SFO      |
-----------------------------------
|  RB-02    |   7   |    SEA      |
-----------------------------------
|  AJ-13    |   9   |    LAX      |
-----------------------------------
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION`..

```
SELECT ITEM_NO, QTY, LOCATION from View_1
UNION
SELECT ITEM_NO, QTY, LOCATION from View_2
```

**OR**, if you *don't care about duplicates*, a more efficient way is `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT ITEM_NO, QTY, LOCATION from View_1
UNION ALL
SELECT ITEM_NO, QTY, LOCATION from View_2
```

The `UNION` will perform a `DISTINCT` internally, where `UNION ALL` will not, hence the better performance.  You should also note, if you want to `ORDER BY` to sort the complete result set, the `ORDER BY` needs to be placed at the **END** of the query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT ITEM_NO, QTY, LOCATION
FROM view_1

UNION ALL

SELECT ITEM_NO, QTY, LOCATION
FROM view_2
```

Answer (score 1):

`UNION`  is used to combine the result-set of several `SELECT` statements.

```
SELECT * 
FROM View_1
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM View_2
```

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/union.html).

Comment: What would happen if one of the views was to change for some reason, new column etc?

Comment: @christiandev in that case we can not apply UNION as you know. I answered according the views' structure he gave us.

Comment: Actually, I was getting to the fact you're using `SELECT *`...You should always specify the columns, so if a new one was added, the query isn't effected.

Comment: @christiandev I understand what you mean, thank you very much for the advice.